# Run a Python Script from Java

Tags: java, python, python-2.7

I want to run a Python2 Script from my Java application but it doesn't run.

I don't get any Stack or Error - It just does not run!

I tried this:

```
public void execPython2(String file, String parm0) {
    try {
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder("python2", file, parm0).start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Here is the method call:

```
public String getMAC(String IP_Addr) {
    execPython2("getMacAddr.py", IP_Addr);    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    String macAddr[] = readFromFile("lastMac.log", false);    
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return macAddr[0];
}
```

The python2 script will create a "lastMac.log" file.

At first I thought the python script would not be finished and I just have to wait until it is finished but i guess the Python script is not even running.

Comment: Regarding `I don't get any Stack or Error`, you need to add `e.printStackTrace();` in all the catch blocks so if there are any exceptions then it would print stack trace on console.

Comment: Yeah, sure i know. But there was no Stack or Error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is a script language - it needs an interpreter to be executed.

So, to be on the safe side - build a comment like

```
 full-path-to-binary/python full-path-to-your-script/yourscript.py
```

*When* you are using a unix-like Operating System and *when* you are writing your script to contain a correct #!/path/to/python statement in its first line, and *when* the script has r+x file system permissions you might not need to do so.

The next step then: your code is **ignoring** any exception. Consider checking error messages instead of ignoring them.

Comment: I know that :)
The path is 150% correct.

Comment: How do you know - your code throws away any exceptions coming from there?!

Comment: Because i only got one Folder^^ Everything is in there. But the Problem was i copyed some files from one dir to another. It seems like the x attrib was lost. I reset the ugo+x and now its running!
Thank you :)

Comment: "150% correct" Whou :)